# Correct pattern to create deferred in Angular2

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular-promise

I've been using angular1.x for a while now and have recently switched to Angular2 which seems to override a few concepts, mainly going away from promises to observables.

In my Ionic2 application I'm parsing some streaming data (serial, if it matters) to match some requests. I have a method that receives all incoming data (as strings). Here's a pattern that I would be using in an angular1.x application:

```
var settingsDeferred = $q.defer();
var settingsDeferred2 = $q.defer();
...
parseData(str) {
 // here I parse the string ...
 if (type of received data is 1){
   if (settingsDeferred){
     settingsDeferred.resolve(parsedData);
   }
 }else if (type of data is 2){
   if (settingsDeferred2){
     settingsDeferred2.resolve(parsedData);
   }
 }
}

requestSpecificData(){
 sendRequestCommand();
 settingsDeferred.promise.then(function(myData){
   console.log('requested data was received');
 }
}

requestSomeOtherData(){
 sendAnotherRequestCommand();
 settingsDeferred2.promise.then(function(myData2){
   console.log('requested data2 was received');
 }
}
```

Obviously this is simplified for brevity but the main functionality would be the same. Since Observables requires (AFAIK) the resolve() to be within their declaration is there any way I can achieve this?

Am I thinking this wrong and should I have an Interpreter pattern with some CommandResponseEvent queue where the parseData above should push events into and the listeners should pull their specific objects out of the queue? That sounds a bit overkill and I also need to listen on an event just before it happens and remove the listener afterwards.

My goal is 5 or 6 simple request/response events, but the incoming stream can contain other data as well in the meantime.
I know I can import the $q library, but perhaps there is a recommended way to do this in the 'Angular 2' way.

I'm using the Ionic2 library so it would be nice if something handling this is already included.

Comment: Would you mind if the solution is entirely written using Observables or you have to use Promise?

Comment: It would be fine, I'm looking for the correct pattern not the exact match of the previous pattern. I've somehow 'solved' the problem using EventEmitter with emit() in sendData, subscribe in the listener methods and calling subscription.dispose() on resolve. Not sure if this is accepted though.